# PostgreSQL "invalid regular expression: invalid escape \ sequence" when using Regex constraint

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, constraints

This is my SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE country (
    id      serial          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name    varchar(100)    NOT NULL CHECK(name ~ '^[-\p{L} ]{2,100}$'),
    code    varchar(3)      NOT NULL
);
```

Notice the *regex* constraint at the `name` attribute. The code above will result in `ERROR: invalid regular expression: invalid escape \ sequence`.

I tried using escape `CHECK(name ~ E'^[-\\p{L} ]{2,100}$')` but again resulted in `ERROR: invalid regular expression: invalid escape \ sequence`.

I am also aware that if I do `CHECK(name ~ '^[-\\p{L} ]{2,100}$'),` or `CHECK(name ~ E'^[-\p{L} ]{2,100}$'),` - the SQL will receive wrong Regex and therefore will throw a constraint violation when inserting valid data.

Does PostgreSQL regex constraints not support regex patterns (`\p`) or something like that?

---

**Edit #1**

The Regex `^[-\p{L} ]{2,100}$` is basically allows country name that are between 2-100 characters and the allowed characters are hyphen, white-space and all letters (including latin letters).

**NOTE:** The SQL runs perfectly fine during the table creation but will throw the error when inserting valid data.

**Additional Note:** I am using PostgreSQL 12.1

Comment: [Edit] the question and explain what the pattern is supposed to match.

Comment: This code [seems to work fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1b791fa306c011f5606369dc2b42b18a).

Comment: `\p{L}` matches any letter, you may get the same behavior using a POSIX character class, `[:alpha:]`, try `'^[-[:alpha:] ]{2,100}$'`

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP `XQuery character class elements using \p{UnicodeProperty} or the inverse \P{UnicodeProperty} are not supported.`. I read: "no - it is not supported".

Comment: @stickybit I edited the question and explained the pattern

Comment: @GMB also sorry, forgot to clarify: "The SQL runs perfectly fine during the table creation but will throw the error when inserting valid data." (it's in the question now)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\p{L}` Unicode category (property) class matches any letter, but it is not supported in [PostgreSQL regex](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP).

You may get the same behavior using a `[:alpha:]` POSIX character class

```
'^[-[:alpha:] ]{2,100}$'
```

Comment: I thought that `[:alpha:]` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z]`? Even on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DxFoZB/1) it does not work, yet it works in the PostgreSQL database. How?

Comment: @ProgramerBeginner So, you already knew about the POSIX character class, good. POSIX character classes are locale-aware in almost all engines where they are used, at least it is true about POSIX compliant regexps. In PostgreSQL, POSIX character classes behave as in POSIX compliant engines, it matches more than just `[A-Za-z]`. As for testing POSIX character classes at regex101.com, you just need to know [how to do it](https://regex101.com/r/82NvdV/1). Watch out, regex101.com does not support POSIX regex testing, only JS, PCRE, Python `re` and Go `regexp` (RE2).